# Javascript - Get the width of an undefined element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dimensions

I have a div element, that has no defined width or height. It holds other elements, and molds on their size. 
I need to get the final size of the div, without being able to check the sizes of the elements inside of it (dynamic elements).

I tried parsing all the properties of the object, but found nothing, all were "undefined".

Any thoughts?

Many thanks

Later edit:

I have

```
<div id="xxx" style="position:relative;">  
    aaaa
</div>
```

I tried:

```
var a = mydiv.style.width;
```

But it did not work.

I also tried:

```
var getKeys = function (obj) {  
    var keys = [];

    for(var key in obj){  
        document.write(key+"="+obj.key+"<br>");  
    }  

    return keys;  
}  

getKeys(mydiv.style);
```

To show all the properties, but none had any info.

The jQuery solution works perfectly, but `getComputedStyle` was what I was looking for, as I can't use jquery here.

Sorry for the short information.

Comment: Show us all the properties which return undefined. You can always get height and width even if you dont assign it explicity. Remember to clear float in case of floated elements

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on no information whatsoever about what you were doing, I'd suggest that you should (if possible) use the `window.getComputedStyle()` approach, which finds the properties of an object as rendered by the browser:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('elemId'),
    properties = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null),
    height = properties.height,
    width = properties.width;
```

If you have jQuery available, then you can simply use the `width()` and `height()` (or `outerWidth()`/`outerHeight()`) methods:

```
var height = $('#elem').height(),
    width = $('#elem').width();
```

Comment: `.getComputedStyle()` won't work in IE8 and older, but there is `.currentStyle` for those.

Comment: @Ana: yeah, I considered adding a reference to that, but without Windows, or IE, to test on at home I didn't have the ability to post a verified-working example code-use. =/

Comment: @DavidThomas it was really helpful, thank you so much...Sir!

Answer (score 4):

You don't give a whole lot of information. I'd suggest you edit your post with the actual code you tried using.

However, with JQuery:

```
$(DOMElement).width()           //-- Element width.
$(DOMElement).innerWidth()      //-- Element width + padding.
$(DOMElement).outerWidth()      //-- Element width + padding & border.
$(DOMElement).outerWidth(true)  //-- Element width + padding, border, and margin.
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('div').width()` will return the width...